# how should I set curl timeout for ftp download?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I'm writing a c++ program, in which I uses libcurl library to download files from ftp server.
If some network error occurs during the download, I hope the program can wait for a while for network reparation or stop downloading when it timeouts.

There are several timeout options in libcurl. Although I read the manual, I still don't know which options to use.

I have tried CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and it seems to set timeout for entire download process.
I also have tried CURLOPT_FTP_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT. When I shutdown the network(using ifdown) during download, the thread holds on for a long time (exceeds the timeout), and when I start up the network(using ifup), it still holds on.

What option should I set if I want the program to timeout when network is failed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I set CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, and then problem solved.